# Сделать 301 редирект постов wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-301

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Нужно организовать 301 редирект для постов, у которых есть категория. Например, пользователь вводит название поста напрямую, получается что-то типа https://my_site/post-example
Если пост относится к какой-то категории, пользователя должно перекинуть на https://my_site/categoty-example/post-example.
Сразу скажу, что уже перепробовал: 1)плагины не подходят, только redirection. В нем можно задать такое поведение, но для каждого поста индивидуально, по-другому адекватно не работает, постов слишком много - не подходит. 2)Написать код, в котором будем получать текущий пост с БД, брать его название, после чего проверка на наличие категории данного поста, и формируем новый url. Тут проблема в том, что приходится задавать значение категории жёстко, если категорий больше, чем одна, то данный скрипт уже не работает.
3)Через файл .htaccess не получится, на беке nginx.
В общем, прошу помощи, может у кого ещё какие-то мысли, с радостью приму советы. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Почему просто в админке на странице постоянных ссылок не задать кастомный url: %category%/%post_name% ?

Comment: Там и так стоит такой url, именно поэтому если пользователь введёт http://my_site/post-example, он увидит перед собой 404-ошибку. А должен быть перенаправлен на url с категорией

Answer (score 0):

Работающий код, который можно добавить в `functions.php` или использовать как `mu-plugin`:

```
<?php

function my_301_redirect() {
    if ( ! is_404() ) {
        return;
    }

    $post_name = trim(
        wp_parse_url(
            filter_var(
                isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) : '',
                FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
            ),
            PHP_URL_PATH
        ),
        '/'
    );

    $args = [
        'name'           => $post_name,
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
    ];

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( ! $query->have_posts() ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_safe_redirect( get_post_permalink( $query->post->ID ), 301 );

    exit;
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_301_redirect' );
```